# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external/images/media match: 1

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I am developing a gallery app and using fabric system to get FC logs from my users. On those logs, several times, I got the FC log :

```
0. Crashed: AsyncQueryWorker: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:169)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:536)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1309)
   at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:105)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

--

Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external/images/media match: 1
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:169)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:536)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1309)
       at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:105)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

0. Crashed: AsyncQueryWorker: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:169)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:536)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1309)
       at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:105)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I think it relates to "AsyncQueryHandler" and "delete" function, so I tried to find the same codes in my project and the only one I got is :

```
sAsyncQueryHandler.startDelete(0, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=?", new String[]{pathname});
```

I tried to search this log on GG but seem noone catches the same problem. If you know why this fc happens / how to fix this, please leave me comments. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the method which you are using. With just one line of code, frankly its difficult to guess whats happening

Comment: @rakeshkashyap For a gallery, after deleting an image, I tried to update the MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI myself by calling sAsyncQueryHandler.startDelete and give the pathname of the image